# Java run Ms Access query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, ms-access

I need to run queries of Ms Access file and the problem is that there is not any sql code to execute from my java code. When I try to see sql code of query

> The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous
>   outer joins

alter is shown. So i must call and run queries. I tried to open and run spesific queries by cmd .bat file. However I cannot find any script for solution. Is there any sql code to run any query from another query? if it is possible it can help me. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call/run a macro in an Access-database from a bat-file and the called macro could run the query via the macro-command `OpenQuery`.

Lets say you name your macro mRunQueryX in Access, within the macro you define the commands:
`OpenQuery` (with the appropiate parameters) and `QuitAccess` (This closes Access after it is started from the bat-file.

Now from your cmd/bat-file you call/run the macro with:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" "[PathToDatabase]\[NameOfTheDatabase].accdb" /X mRunQueryX

The path to MSACCESS.EXE varies with the Office-version.